# mutableCopy()について

Tags: swift

Stringを、NSMutableStringにcastする際、以下のようにmutableCopy()を使用します。

```
var sample1: String = "aaabbb"
var sample2: NSMutableString = sample1.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString
```

しかし、[String Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:SS)を見ても、StringはmutableCopyメソッドは持っていないようで、[NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/)を確認すると、NSObjectが持っていました。

Stringは構造体のため、NSObjectを継承していないはずです。
なぜ、StringでmutableCopy()が使用できるようのでしょうか？

XCode 7.1 Swift 2 を使用しています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Structure ReferenceのObjective-C Bridgeに書かれています

ざっくりいうとStringはNSStringと同じものとして使えますということです

ですからStringはNSStringが使用できる全てのメソッドが使用可能です（細かく調べていないので一部例外があるかもしれません）